# linux-headers-3.5.0.19 needs to be installed but I can't find a archive for it. Please help!

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-center, sudo

This error keeps showing up. I can't update through the little red circle caution symbol and when I open the software center it stalls and then shuts down.

I tried to do the `sudo apt-get install -f` thing, but that just said `"could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open"`

What does this all mean? If anyone can help, please use new-user-friendly words and be descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

I have linux-headers-3.5.0-19 in my default package list itself, I don't need to add any additional ppas.

What I understand from your description is that there are broken dependencies on your system. You can try completely removing the packages for which there are conflicts. If it works, then try and reinstall them once again.

The second issue happened probably because you had Synaptic open, and you tried sudo apt-get install -f from the terminal. Is this right?

Comment: I eventually just reinstalled the os. I had only had it up and runing for a our before I found this problem so I thought this wouldn't hurt. IT WORKED! Everything is now working perfectly! I now updated everything, and I have downloaded several things in the Ubuntu software center

Comment: Nice that you got it working.